# Magento 2.1 - Display RRP attribute beside price

Tags: magento-2.1

I added a custom attribute to use for RRP and I need it to display along side the price on both the product page and product list. From digging around it looks like I can override the price template here...

app\design\frontend[theme]\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\price\amount\default.phtml

I tried, adding...

```
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$attvalue = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('rrp')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
echo 'RRP: '.$attvalue;
```

However it produced an error.

Comment: show us the error

Comment: Hi Philipp. My apologies, I should have included the error. Here it is...
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getResource() on null

Comment: well this is quite clear that the product is null.